# Android Studio Is not launching

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I click on the Android Studio icon, it is not launching. A few days ago (about 5 days ago) I used android studio and it worked, after use I open Android Studio after 5 days and it is not launching... 
[See Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQu3D-kg7qQ)

Comment: Open the task manager and see if the Android Studio process starts. If it does, give of some time since it is a heavy program. The loading screen would come in some time. If nothing works try reinstalling it.

Comment: try to uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: 3 GB of RAM is minimum recommended for the current version of Android Studio. I see you have only 2 GB. This will make the system to use the paging file which will be VERY slow. What is your free space on C: ? If it is low, you cannot really execute Android Studio at all.

Comment: Free Space in C: is 18.6 GB... Ram is 2 GB but i used android studio 5 days ago in 2 GB it is working at that time... Please Solve....

Comment: I have Uninstalled and Reinstalled... Android Studio task is not processing in Task Manager

Answer (score 4):

Current version of Android Studio (2.3.3) needs 3 GB of RAM. You only have 2 GB, as seen on your video. The operating system will try to use the paging file which is slow, but furthermore if you have low disc space at C:, you cannot execute Android Studio.
[Android Studio Minimum Requirements](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

Comment: Free Space in C: is 18.6 GB... Ram is 2 GB but i used android studio 5 days ago in 2 GB it is working at that time... Please Solve....

Comment: Probably it was updated to the newer version, which now asks for more RAM but it cannot find it and does not start. Upgrading from 2 GB to 4 GB is cheap. I have 8 GB RAM, 2.8 GHz dual core, 64 bit version, SSD. But still not very comfortable with Android Studio. You really need a good machine to work on Android otherwise you are going to look at your clock waiting...

Answer (score 0):

Go to this location and start your android studio(Please check our C:(Drive) Space).

`Go to-C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio(application)`

Comment: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe... I open But not Opening... Same Problem...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue while launching android studio with ./studio.sh via terminal but it was not working neither clicking on the icon helped. But just placing sudo before above command does the job.
Go to your android installation directory where studio.sh file is present and open in terminal then run

```
sudo ./studio.sh
```